# XSL Remove element on value and add new element with concatenated value(1,2,3..)

Tags: xslt, element

I a very much new to XSLT and some help to move forward. I was able to use the XSL to get only the false success values,but to get all the QUEID values as shown in output.xml as a list, 
 I could not go forward. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
            XSL
            =========
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
                <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
                <xsl:variable name="gb"/>
                <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>
                <xsl:template match="//Entity[success='true']"/>
            </xsl:stylesheet>


            Input XML
            ==============
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <Entities>
                <Entity>
                    <Type/>
                    <QUEID>14077317</QUEID>
                    <ENUM>95299168</ENUM>
                    <success>false</success>
                </Entity>
                <Entity>
                    <Type/>
                    <QUEID>14077319</QUEID>
                    <ENUM>95299151</ENUM>
                    <success>false</success>
                </Entity>
                <Entity>
                    <Type/>
                    <QUEID>14077320</QUEID>
                    <ENUM>95299154</ENUM>
                    <success>true</success>
                </Entity>
                <Entity>
                    <Type/>
                    <QUEID>14077328</QUEID>
                    <ENUM>95299164</ENUM>
                    <success>false</success>
                </Entity>
                <Entity>
                    <Type/>
                    <QUEID>14077329</QUEID>
                    <ENUM>95299147</ENUM>
                    <success>true</success>
                </Entity>
            </Entities>


            Desired Output XML
            ===================
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <Entities>
                <Entity>
                    <Type/>
                    <QUEID>102</QUEID>
                    <ENUM>98</ENUM>
                    <success>true</success>
                </Entity>
                <Entity>
                    <Type/>
                    <QUEID>104</QUEID>
                    <ENUM>67</ENUM>
                    <success>true</success>
                </Entity>
                      <EntityList>102,104</EntityList>
            </Entities>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to say whether it's XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. In 2.0, add the template rule

```
<xsl:template match="Entities">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <EntityList>
    <xsl:value-of select="//Entity[success='false']/QUEID" separator=","/>
  </EntityList>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks very much., its XSLT 2.0 can I get the complete XSL that can be the desired output, that would be of great help

Comment: No, I don't write code for people, I try to help them write it themselves.